Staging ground questions appear on homepage while review suspended
This is more of a nitpick than anything, but I figured it's worth noting. Got review suspended (no stigma here) and I'm still able to see recent activity for staging ground questions on the homepage.

It's not like it lets me bypass the suspension and review the post, I get blocked by the page itself:

But maybe a review suspension should be treated like you have the "show staging ground question" setting disabled.
I've also found that this post mentions the potential for separate review suspensions and staging ground suspensions. If this happens, then this edge-case might pop up a second time. Might be worth just waiting for that day, though.

The plan for the initial test is to use review queue suspensions for this: when a user is suspended from the review queue, they will also be suspended from the Staging Ground (and vice versa). Implementing a separate suspension system is not in the scope of our test release, and it seems fair to say that a user who needs a suspension from one section on the site could also use one on the other. If there is a need for a separate suspension system for the Staging Ground in the future, this can be addressed at that time.


We pushed a change to hide the Staging Ground questions from the question list and homepage if a reviewer has been temporarily suspended. As such, I've updated the tag to status-completed
